# Need help in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to calculate the sum of 5 numbers in an array with recursion. However, I am getting the output as 0 from the recursive function. If I uncomment the print statement I am getting the sum as 15 but the function is returning the sum as 0.  What am I doing wrong here??

My code-

```
def calcsum(arr):
  i = 0
  sum = 0
  solution(arr,sum,i)
  return sum

def solution(arr,sum,i):
  if i == len(arr):
    return

  sum = sum + arr[i]
  #print(sum,i)
  solution(arr,sum,i+1)

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that recursion has at least two cases:

- Base case: return the aggregate value
- Recursive case: return the result of recursing

You're not returning a value from either case! Try this instead:

```py
def solution(arr, sum_, i):
    if i == len(arr):
        return sum_

    sum_ += arr[i]
    return solution(arr, sum_, i+1)
```

Additionally, merely calling `solution` does not change the value of `sum` in `calcsum`, so `return sum` will always give `0`. Try instead:

```py
def calcsum(arr):
    return solution(arr, 0, 0)
```

(an aside, this sort of construction where you create a function which delegates the call to a helper with some added arguments reminds me a lot of Haskell, where you might write:

```hs
calcsum :: Num a => [a] -> a
calcsum = go 0 0
  where go :: Num a => Int -> Int -> [a] -> a
        go acc idx xs
            | length xs >= idx = acc
            | otherwise        = go (acc + (xs !! idx)) idx+1 xs
```

Also your logic is a little convoluted. Consider instead something like:

```py
def solution(arr):
    if arr:
        # Recursive case
        x, rest = arr[0], arr[1:]
        return x + solution(rest)
    else:
        # Base case
        return 0
```

The base case now is when `arr` is empty (rather than when you've passed an index that's outside the array). You calculate the sum of the empty list which can only logically by `0`. The recursive case pulls the first element off the list and adds it to the solution for the rest of the list.

Comment: also in `calcsum`: `sum = 0; solution(arr,sum,i); return sum` calling `solution` doesn't change that local variable in place.

Comment: The first of the two codes you give looks much better than the second one, yet you call the first one convoluted. Writing `rest = arr[1:]` in the second piece of code makes a copy of the array. Since you make a new copy at each recursive call, you will make as many copies of the array as there are elements! And since making a copy takes linear time, the whole algorithm takes quadratic time! This is much less efficient than the first code.

Comment: @Stef If you're looking for efficiency, you're writing the wrong language. (C)Python does not have efficient recursive functions. Full stop. The latter is clear to the reader, the former is not. If you're writing Python that's probably all you care about.

Comment: @Stef idiomatic code beats highly optimized code 99 times out of 100. If you were interested in cheap summation, you wouldn't use recursion at all https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2021857

Comment: @Stef -- also, if efficiency was the goal, one would just write `sum(arr)`

Comment: Dear @AdamSmith , I hope you're not suggesting making `len(arr)` copies of the array `arr` is an idiomatic way of calculating the sum of the elements in the array. Just because it's possible to write inefficient code doesn't mean it's wise to encourage beginners to write the most inefficient possible code. The op looks like they want to learn how to use function calls correctly, and different ways to iterate over an array. You are telling them "looping with an index is convoluted; you should instead make tons of copies of the array". Do you believe this will help them learn?

Comment: ”recursion has two cases...” ... _at minimum_. It reads like there’s an implied limit of cases, not allowing for the possibility for more sophisticated schemes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, you should *return* the sum. Here's an iterator version:

```
def calcsum(arr):
    return solution(iter(arr), 0)

def solution(it, sum):
    for x in it:
        return solution(it, sum + x)
    return sum

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Shorter way using only one function and only one parameter, adding `x` *after* the recursion:

```
def calcsum(it):
    it = iter(it)
    for x in it:
        return x + calcsum(it)
    return 0

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Both solutions take linear time, unlike the similar solution that takes only `arr` and splits it into `arr[0]` and `arr[1:]`, which takes overall quadratic time. A little benchmark comparing this iterator version with that list version by summing a list of 1000 values:

```
0.28 ms  calcsum_1
2.70 ms  calcsum_2
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat

def calcsum_1(it):
    it = iter(it)
    for x in it:
        return x + calcsum_1(it)
    return 0

def calcsum_2(arr):
    if arr:
        x, rest = arr[0], arr[1:]
        return x + calcsum_2(rest)
    return 0

arr = [1] * 1000

for _ in range(3):
    for f in calcsum_1, calcsum_2:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: f(arr), number=1000))
        print('%.2f ms ' % t, f.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: I love how this function actually works even though the `for` loop actually never runs for more than one iteration.

Comment: @Stef It's my favorite way to extract only one value and be able to handle emptiness. Short and fast (I did benchmarks [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/250053/72846), for example). Just added a shorter solution here, btw.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least five issues with your code:

- The call to `solution(arr, sum, i)` in `calcsum` does not modify `calcsum`'s local variable `sum`, thus `calcsum` always returns 0;
- You wrote `return` instead of `return sum` in the end case for the recursion in `solution`, so `solution` will return `None` instead of returning the sum in that case
- You wrote the recursive call as `solution(arr,sum,i+1)` instead of `return solution(arr,sum,i+1)` or `some_variable = solution(arr,sum,i+1)`, so the return value of the recursive call is ignored anyway; there is no `return` statement except the one inside the `if` block, so the function `solution` will not have a return value (or more precisely, it will return `None`);
- You seem to believe that modifying `sum` inside `solution` will modify any variable called `sum` throughout your program. This is wrong. `sum` is a local variable of the function, and modifying it has no impact on the rest of the program.
- Calling a variable `sum` is a bad idea in python; this is the name of a builtin function, so you should try to find another name for your variables.

To illustrate the fourth point, try out this code:

```py
def mostly_harmless(n):
  n = 7

n = 8
mostly_harmless(n)
print('Does this set n to 7? Am I about to print 8 or 7?')
print(n)

print()

mostly_harmless(12)
print('did we set 12 = 7? did we just break all of mathematics?')
print('making sure 12 is still 12:')
print(12)
print('making sure n is still n:')
print(n)
```

With this in mind, we can fix your code:

```py
def calcsum(arr):
  return solution(arr, 0, 0)

def solution(arr, sum, i):
  if i == len(arr):
    return sum
  else:
    return solution(arr, sum + arr[i], i+1)

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Actually, we can simplify the code further using default arguments:

```py
def calcsum(arr, sum=0, i=0):
  if i == len(arr):
    return sum
  else:
    return calcsum(arr, sum + arr[i], i+1)

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

But note that python is **not** a language that likes recursion. In some other programming languages, recursion is very good, and exactly as efficient as for loops and while loops. But that is not the case in python. In python, recursion is much slower than loops, and uses much more memory. We can rewrite your program with a for loop:

```py
def calcsum(arr):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    sum += arr[i]
  return sum

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Or even better:

```py
def calcsum(arr):
  sum = 0
  for v in arr:
    sum += v
  return sum

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Also note that calling a variable `sum` in python is a bad idea, because `sum` is the name of a builtin function in python. You can find a list of builtins in [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html); try to give other names to your variables.

The function `sum`, unsurprisingly, calculates the sum all by itself:

```py
print(sum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

So why was it so bad to call a variable `sum`? Well, then we lose access to the builtin function with the same name:

```py
sum = 7
print(sum([1,2,3,4,5]))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Normally `sum` refers to the builtin function; but now it refers to a variable equal to `7`; when I try to call `sum([1,2,3,4,5])`, it's as if I tried to call `7([1,2,3,4,5])`, which doesn't make sense because `7` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work "your way", i.e., increase the `sum` variable in `calcsum`, if you put `solution` inside of it and increase the outer `sum` instead of having its own. No need to pass `arr` then, either.

```
def calcsum(arr):

  def solution(i):
    nonlocal sum
    if i == len(arr):
      return

    sum = sum + arr[i]
    solution(i+1)

  sum = 0
  solution(0)
  return sum

print(calcsum([1,2,3,4,5]))
```